# setBinaryStream(int, InputStream) is not yet implemented

Tags: postgresql, jsp, byte

Hello i'm newbie at jsp programming. i'm trying to insert a image in PostgreSQL database with byte field. Here is my code so far.

jsp code

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Test image</h1>
            <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="description" />
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
InputStream inputStream = null;  

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request  
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");  
        if (filePart != null) {  
            // debug messages  
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());  
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());  
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());  

            // obtains input stream of the upload file  
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();  
        }  

         try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8084/hgcirequestproject", "appdev2", "Hgc@dm1nD3v310p3r2k14");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into tbl_testimage (test) values (?)");
         ps.setBinaryStream(1, inputStream);

            ps.executeQuery();
            out.println("success");
            con.close();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }



    }

}
```

i got the error .setBinaryStream(int, InputStream) is not yet implemented.
any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use [the 3-argument `setBinaryStream` variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long)) that supplies the length in bytes of the stream's contents.

The PostgreSQL wire protocol requires that the length be sent before the data its self, so PgJDBC has to know the length.

[Newer versions of PgJDBC support the 2-argument form by buffering the stream first](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/220).